# django rest framework - foreign key fields are read only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_num = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields...
    class Meta:
       unique_together = [('company', 'item_num') ]
```

Serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('company_id', 'item_num', )
```

The problem is that django rest framework generates a `ReadOnlyField()` for the `company_id` field, so this field is not editable when I create a new instance in view code like this:

```
s = ItemSerializer(data=request.POST)
s.save()
```

I also lose the default `UniqueTogetherValidator` that is defined in the model.
Though, if I change the serializer field name from 'company_id' to 'company', I do get the validator, as drf will generate `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` so it will be editable.

How can I still name my foreign key objects like 'company_id', because I do prefer naming them like this, and still get the default validation and saving behavior? Preferably without adding to much code to the serializer.

Answer (score 5):

`company_id` is a read-only field because it lacks a proper definition in the Model for the serializer to understand it.
Steps to get it working:

1. Add an explicit field definition
2. Add the constraint

Serializer would be:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source=company, queryset=Company.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('company_id', 'item_num', )
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Item.objects.all(),
                fields=('company_id', 'item_num')
            )
        ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use `company_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` instead of IntegerField() ? And is it possible to do this without redefining the model validations?

Comment: My bad, you're right, it should be `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`

Comment: It would be possible to avoid explicit validators declaration it you kept the name `company` instead of `company_id`